# Checking data integrity on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

We collect data on a form. Then, the form is submitted via the web. Sometimes the network connection is unavailable, so it gets stored in a .plist file.

Is there a way (in XCode or otherwise) to pull that plist file from the iPhone? I specifically want to see the state of that file after a crash, but before I start the app again.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but Background App Refresh might be helpful in your case.